# FPDF Get page numbers at footer on Every A4 size page

Tags: php, fpdf

I am creating PDF reports using FPDF. Now how do I generate page numbers on each page of a report at the bottom of the page. 
Below is the sample code for generating a 2 page PDF.

```
<?php
        require('fpdf.php');

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',16);

        $start_x=$pdf->GetX(); 
        $current_y = $pdf->GetY();
        $current_x = $pdf->GetX();

        $cell_width = 25; $cell_height=14; 
        $j = 20;  // This value will be coming from Database so we dont know how many pages the report is going to be 
        for ($i = 0; $i<$j ; $i++){
            $pdf->MultiCell($cell_width,$cell_height,'Hello1',1);
            $current_x+=$cell_width;
            $pdf->Ln();
        }

        $pdf->Output();


        ?>
```

Note : The $j value will be coming from the database so we don't know how many pages is the report going to be.

Comment: May a lil late but with this code you will produce only 1 page. To add more pages you have to add more `$pdf->AddPage()` may into your `for`-loop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add an A4 page, with portrait orientation, do:

```
$pdf->AddPage("P","A4");
```

Create a new class which extends the `FPDF` class, and override the pre-defined `Footer` method.

**Example:**

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Footer()
    {
        // Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Select Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Print centered page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call this Footer method from my code ? Can you please tell me.

Comment: For the above code I have added $pdf = new PDF(); and it worked for me. thanks.!!

Comment: Header and Footer functions don't need to be called separately. If you extend FPDF and then instantiate, those are called automatically.

Answer (score 17):

According to my comment you can place

```
$pdf->PageNo();
```

on your page where ever you like. Also you can add a placeholder to this

```
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
```

What would look like

```
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{totalPages}');
```

> By default it's {nb}. It's not necessary to add a placeholder

Than you could add the pagesum like

```
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, "Page " . $pdf->PageNo() . "/{totalPages}", 0, 1);
```

or without your own placeholder

```
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, "Page " . $pdf->PageNo() . "/{nb}", 0, 1);
```

this would produce e.g.

> Page 1/10

in case there were 10 pages :)

**But beware**

> Using the placeholder will mess up the width of the cell. So if you have e.g. 180 page-width than 90 isn't the mid anymore **(*In the line where you use the placeholder*)**. You will see if you try :)

Comment: To not destroy the layout too much I used "#" instead of "{totalPages}" as placeholder. Works great!

Comment: I am using fpdf_merge to merge multiple dynamically created pdf files.  This methods works well for individual files that go lets say from 1/4 to 4/4, but I would like to pass over the merged pdf andd add a new pagination on each page instead.  Any way to review a pdf page by page and add a page number?

Comment: @AlexVio have you tried to use FPDI to import the pdf, edit every page and save it again?
I dont know if this works but this would be my first attempt