# How to get half of total pages in FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I was able to get the total page number using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753991/fpdf-get-page-numbers-at-footer-on-every-a4-size-page) answer (second one), but is there a way to get half of the total pages in FPDF?

I tried with

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->totalPages = '{totalPages}';
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{totalPages}');
$pdf->halftotalPages = $pdf->totalPages / 2;
```

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

As `$pdf->totalPages` is `{totalPages}` and it is not a number. How can I get half of the total pages?

Comment: Check this value `$pdf->AliasNbPages();`

Comment: `$pdf->totalPages = '{totalPages}';` "and is not a number" - yeah.. you declared it as a string?

Comment: if you mean this -> `var_dump($pdf->AliasNbPages())` i am getting `NULL`

Comment: @treyBake, that makes sense, but how can I fix it?

Comment: @Dimitar you could do `$pdf->PageNo / 2` maybe?

Comment: @treyBake, `$pdf->PageNo()` will get me current page and not total pages, so this will not work

Comment: @Dimitar well, where/why are you trying to get half count?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195691/discussion-between-dimitar-and-treybake).